# Spring mvc - How to map all wrong request mapping to a single method

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am using a spring(version 3.2.5) annotation driven  mvc application, basically I need be able to catch any wrong url to a single method then display an error message. For instance, if my correct `url www.url.valid/login` maps to a controller, if the user mistakenly insert **loginw** or any invalid url it should map to a default controller.

I have tried the following way:

```
package com.controller;

import static com.mns.utils.Constants.REGISTER_FAIL;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class DefaultSpringController {

      @RequestMapping
      public String forwardRequest(final HttpServletRequest request) {
         return "redirect:/" + REGISTER_FAIL;
      }

}
```

My Application context is as follows:

```
    <!-- Default to DefaultSpringController -->
     <bean id="defaultSpringController"  class="com.controller.DefaultSpringController">
     </bean>

  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">
    <property name="defaultHandler" ref="defaultSpringController"/>
  </bean
```

But kept getting the following error:

```
nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.controller.DefaultSpringController
```

I am not sure what I am missing here, and the controller is in the correct package.

Any idea how I can achieve it please?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

It look like, you want a global page not found handler.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionContoller {

    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public String handleError404(HttpServletRequest request, Exception e) {
        return "pageNotFoundViewNameGoesHere";
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi it looks like version 3.2.5 NoHandlerFoundException not available,i am getting compilation error

Comment: Since 4.0. My suggestion is using latest version.

Comment: just my 2 cents: this will not work for example with request `/login/asdasd`.

Comment: I am using 4.3.3.RELEASE version of spring and it is ok

Comment: @AfsunKhammadli no, it is not: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.3.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html#setUseSuffixPatternMatch-boolean-

Answer (score 2):

You can set config at `web.xml` for invalid `url`. Note that invalid `url` usually throw the `404` error page.

```
<error-page>
        <error-code>404</error-code>
        <location>/error/error.jsp</location>
    </error-page>
```

If it's not enough, you can go your controller method from this error page. But I usually use this config for error page instead of server side code. There have many other alternatives ways depend on your technologies usage but this way can reduce your code.

Answer (score 1):

If you define a `ExceptionHandler`, keep in mind, that the wrong requests like `/login/blabla` will not throw an `NoHandlerFoundException`, because the suffix pattern math is [activated by default](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/method/annotation/RequestMappingHandlerMapping.html#setUseSuffixPatternMatch-boolean-).

Therefore just to define an `ExceptionHandler` is not enough to catch **all** wrong requests.

In this case follow these steps:

**First step**. configure your application to throw an exception for unmapped calls like `/login/blabla` (*SuffixPattern + TrailingSlashMatch*):

```
@Configuration
public class WebAppMainConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {  

    @Override 
    public void configurePathMatch(PathMatchConfigurer configurer) {
        // will throw NoHandlerFoundException
        configurer.setUseSuffixPatternMatch(false);
        configurer.setUseTrailingSlashMatch(false);
    }

    [...]
}
```

**Second step**. define exception handler:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND)
    @ExceptionHandler(NoHandlerFoundException.class)
    public Object handleException(NoHandlerFoundException ex, HttpServletRequest request) {
        [...]
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return "error";
    }

}
```

Comment: This is not working in my case, actually I have exluded RepositoryRestMvcAutoConfiguration.class, is that the reason its not working ?

Comment: Could you please guide me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59950440/how-to-wrap-path-not-found-exception-in-spring-boot-rest-using-exceptionhandler ?