# How to wrap Path Not Found Exception in Spring Boot Rest using ExceptionHandler?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-rest

I am using Spring Boot and Spring Rest Example. In this example, I am passing custom header, if that value is valid, endpoint gets called successfully, if custom header value is not correct then I get below response, which I want to wrap into show it to the enduser using `@ControllerAdvice` ExceptionHandler.

Note: I went through [Spring mvc - How to map all wrong request mapping to a single method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504501/spring-mvc-how-to-map-all-wrong-request-mapping-to-a-single-method), but here in my case I am taking decision based on CustomHeader.

```
{
    "timestamp": "2020-01-28T13:47:16.201+0000",
    "status": 404,
    "error": "Not Found",
    "message": "No message available",
    "path": "/employee-data/employee-codes"
}
```

Controller

```
@Operation(summary = "Find Employee")
@ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "SUCCESS"),
        @ApiResponse(code = 500, message = "Internal Server Error") })
@Parameter(in = ParameterIn.HEADER, description = "X-Accept-Version", name = "X-Accept-Version", 
        content = @Content(schema = @Schema(type = "string", defaultValue = "v1", 
        allowableValues = {HeaderConst.V1}, implementation = Country.class)))
@GetMapping(value = "/employees/employee-codes", headers = "X-Accept-Version=v1")
public ResponseEntity<Employees> findEmployees(
        @RequestParam(required = false) String employeeCd,
        @RequestParam(required = false) String firstName,
        @RequestParam(required = false) Integer lastName) {
    Employees response = employeeService.getEmployees(employeeCd, firstName, lastName);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(response, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

I've implemented `HttpMessageNotReadableException` and `HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException` and `NoHandlerFoundException`, but still not able to wrap this error.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to find the solution for it.

```
# Whether a "NoHandlerFoundException" should be thrown if no Handler was found to process a request.
spring.mvc.throw-exception-if-no-handler-found=true
spring.resources.add-mappings=false
```

**Error Handling Code:**

```
@Override
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleNoHandlerFoundException(NoHandlerFoundException ex, HttpHeaders headers,
        HttpStatus status, WebRequest request) {
    // custom logic here

    return handleExceptionInternal(ex, error, getHeaders(), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `@ControllerAdvice`,
do this:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RestResponseEntityExceptionHandler 
  extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler {
 
    @ExceptionHandler(value 
      = { IllegalArgumentException.class, IllegalStateException.class })
    protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleConflict(
      RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
        String bodyOfResponse = "This should be application specific";
        return handleExceptionInternal(ex, bodyOfResponse, 
          new HttpHeaders(), HttpStatus.CONFLICT, request);
    }
}
```

Comment: Check out this Baeldung article for more details: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring